# Can a patch in net logo have two color and one is hidden sometimes?

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a tree grow in net logo, I have to implement a hidden trunk. But how can I make a patch assign to trunk color when there is no leaf and sometimes hidden behind leaves and showing leaf color ?

When we standing in front a tree, we sometimes cannot see the upper trunk cause the leaves. That is what I am going to model for now.

Comment: The colour of a patch is set by the variable `pcolor`. You can just `ask` the patch to set the colour based on whatever condition you are using to judge whether the trunk is visible.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the answer you were hoping to get, but it might be the one that helps you the most in the long run:

**The tree leaves should not be represented by patches. They should be represented by turtles.**

If you use turtles, you get the "hiding what's behind" property for free, but that's just one of the reasons to use turtles.

NetLogo beginners tend to resort to patches as their "go-to" type of agents because they seem easier to use, but it's a trap. Turtles are much more flexible, and it pays to use them in the long run, even if you don't expect to move them around.

A few examples:

- Patches are just coloured squares, but turtles can be any [shape](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#turtle-shapes) you want, which usually looks nicer. In your case, you could use the `"leaf"` shape that comes with NetLogo.
- Turtles can have different [breeds](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#breeds). Even if you plan to only use one breed of turtles, this makes your code more readable and also more flexible.
- You can't have [links](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links) between patches, but you can have links between turtles. Even if your model is not explicitly a network model, NetLogo links are a surprisingly useful way to represent relationship between agents.
- Turtles can be created and killed. This is often a much better approach than trying to modify the state of a patch to reflect the fact that something is there or not. This applies directly to your problem: instead of changing the colour of a patch to signal that there is a leaf on it, just ask your patch to `sprout-leaves 1`.

So do yourself a favour and start your model with:

```
breed [ leaves leaf ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape leaves "leaf"
  ; ...
  reset-ticks
end
```

You'll make your own life much easier.